# digest authentication for application deployed on jboss 7.2

Tags: hash, callback, jboss

I have configured the login-module in the web.xml of the application running on jboss7.2

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
        <realm-name>newrealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

The jboss-web.xml is configured with the security-domain

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>securitydomain1</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

The standalone.xml is configured with the security-domain as follows

```
<security-domain name="RPAHttps" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="D:\jboss7\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\configuration\rpahttpsusers.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="D:\jboss7\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\configuration\rpahttpsroles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="defaultUsersProperties" value="D:\jboss7\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\configuration\rpahttpsusers.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="defaultRolesProperties" value="D:\jboss7\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\configuration\rpahttpsroles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="rfc2617"/>
                            <module-option name="ignorePasswordCase" value="false"/>
                            <module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="false"/>
                            <module-option name="passwordIsA1Hash" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="storeDigestCallback" value="org.jboss.security.auth.callback.RFC2617Digest"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

I generated the password stored in the property files as shown below

```
D:\jboss7\jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main>java -classpath picketbox-5.0.3.Final-redhat-3.jar org.jboss.security.auth.callback.RFC2617Digest TD-ADMIN new_1015 RPAHttpsRealm
RFC2617 A1 hash: cdb6fe455334228532b07355043afcb6
```

Please note i gave same value in storeDigestCall back module option. I had tried other call back classes in vain

i am getting the following error , could you please help

UG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-2) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@234fd496 for /rpaws/services/SearchIPAddressPort
03:19:06,161 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00281: Password hashing activated, algorithm: MD5, encoding: rfc2617, charset: null, callback: null, storeCallBack: org.jboss.security.auth.callback.RFC2617Digest
03:19:06,173 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00283: Bad password for username TD-ADMIN
03:19:06,173 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX00070: Password invalid/Password required
at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:286)
at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.login(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:171)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:726)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574)
at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:406)
at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345)
at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:323)
at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:123)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verify(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:89)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.digest.DigestAuthenticationMechanism.handleDigestHeader(DigestAuthenticationMechanism.java:312)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.digest.DigestAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(DigestAuthenticationMechanism.java:170)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:245)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:268)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:231)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:125)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:99)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:92)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

03:19:06,175 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-2) Authentication failed with message UT000038: Authentication failed, requested user name 'TD-ADMIN' and mechanism DIGEST for HttpServerExchange{ POST /rpaws/services/SearchIPAddressPort request {Connection=[Keep-Alive], SOAPAction=[""], Authorization=[Digest username="TD-ADMIN", realm="RPAHttpsRealm", nonce="RFQLuAOrMiANMTU5ODIxOTM0NjE1NGdPOKC+2c1pRogJZwM8eYU=", uri="/rpaws/services/SearchIPAddressPort", response="a0e500d779a876633b968e0180f3da42", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="c18eb749fd10230c", algorithm=MD5, opaque="00000000000000000000000000000000"], Accept-Encoding=[gzip,deflate], Content-Type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[652], User-Agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/12.0.1)], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Expires=[0], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache]}}

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue, but your additions to the standalone.xml file got this working for me.  Here is how I did this.  Hopefully it helps someone.

This was performed on Jboss-EAP 7.2.9

1. Add a user and password that will be used for the DIGEST authentication.

```
$ cd ./modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main
$ java -classpath picketbox-5.0.3.Final-redhat-3.jar org.jboss.security.auth.callback.RFC2617Digest username PAssword1234 ApplicationRealm
RFC2617 A1 hash: 03e86946408b9e9c85c7b62f3d811062
```

2. Add the username and hash to the ./standalone/configuration/application-users.properties file

```
username=03e86946408b9e9c85c7b62f3d811062
```

3. Add the role to the ./standalone/configuration/application-roles.properties

```
username=RoleName
```

4. In my application's jboss-web.xml file

```
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <security-domain>filesystemSD</security-domain>
    <context-root>rest</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

5. At the bottom of my application's web.xml file, I added this:

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>rest</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>RoleName</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
      <role-name>RoleName</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <login-config>
      <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
      <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
  </login-config>

</web-app>
```

6. I then ran these three jboss-cli commands

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=filesystemSD:add
/subsystem=security/security-domain=filesystemSD/authentication=classic:add
/subsystem=security/security-domain=filesystemSD/authentication=classic/login-module=UsersRoles:add(code=UsersRoles,flag=required,module-options=["usersProperties"=>"file:///${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties", \
"rolesProperties"=>"file:///${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties", \
"hashAlgorithm"=>"MD5",\
"hashEncoding"=>"rfc2617",\
"ignorePasswordCase"=>"false",\
"hashStorePassword"=>"true",\
"hashUserPassword"=>"false",\
"passwordIsA1Hash"=>"true",\
"storeDigestCallback"=>"org.jboss.security.auth.callback.RFC2617Digest"])
```

7. Then reload jboss and deploy the application.  When a user attempts to access /rest/, they will be prompted for the username and password that you created in step 1